# imported my module: not defined (python 3.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x

help, I made a small module but it is no working!!! (python 3.4)

This is all it contains:

```
def run(file):
    exec(open(file).read())
```

when I import it and when i type: run('example.py')

it says that 'run' is not defined!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand on Reily's answer you also use:

```
from my_module import run

run(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need refer to the run function within the module where it is defined. Assuming that this is in 'my_module.py' then at the Python prompt:

```
>>> import my_module
>>> my_module.run('example.py')
```